# AngularJs: Directive with function for template property. How to get scope value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to have **different templates for directive**. All solutions that I've found were about using **$compile service** inside linker function.

But we have `template` property for directive factory that can be a function. Why not to use this option?

So:

```
return {
  template: function(element, attr) {
    if(attr.template){
      return attr.template;
    }
    return defaultTemplate;
  }
}
```

and after in html:

```
<my-directive template="button.template"></my-directive>
```

Works like charm.
Only one thing is missing: I don't know how to get scope variable `button.template` inside. Now just getting 'button.template' like a string. Also tried with brackets - same string only with brackets '{{button.template}}'. Is it possible or I should return back to solution with compile service?

Comment: I think this won't work as your template function is called before `{{button.template}}` is evaluated. I guess this is just a simplified example of your directive, otherwise you could maybe use `ng-include`.

Comment: yes, you are right, it's simplified version. But could you tell me more about your idea with ng-include? how are you going to put template from scope variable there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template` function is executed *before* the linking phase. This means that the scope is not yet available when it is evaluated (and this is why it is not injected into the function).

The pattern is to inject `$compile` into your directive factory and use it in the `postLink` phase, because at that time, the scope *is* already available. For example,

```
app.directive('myDirective', [ '$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Here, both the DOM and the scope are available, so
            // you can extend the DOM with templates compiled against the scope

            // if you are using <my-directive template="button.template"></my-directive>
            var template = scope.$eval(attrs.template);

            // if you are using <my-directive template="{{ button.template }}"></my-directive>
            var template = attrs.template;  // interpolation is already processed against the scope

            // compile the template and append to existing DOM
            element.append($compile(template || defaultTemplate)(scope));
        }

        function template(element, attrs) {
            // Here, you cannot evaluate attrs.template against the scope
            // because the scope does not yet exist! Only the DOM is
            // available (you can use the raw values of attributes if needed)
            return '<div></div>';
        }

        return {
            template: template,
            link: postLink
        }
    }
])
```